# How the element $x$ is different from $\{x\}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-theory

In Discrete Math, it's trivial to say that $x \ne \{x\}$, why is that?

Comment: $x\in\{x\}$, but $\{x\}\notin x$.

Comment: Think of sets as trash cans that have objects in them (although the empty set -- an empty trash can -- is allowed). $x$ is an object (which might be a trash can itself, either empty or not empty), and $\{x\}$ is what you have when you put $x$ in a trash can.

Comment: @Dave: With analogies like these no wonder people think of set theory as a system with "garbage theorems". :-D

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: I came up with this sometime in the mid 1980s when teaching a low level "finite matheamtics" class (the kind taken by non-science majors for their required university math elective; basically one of those [math appreciation courses](https://doi.org/10.2307/2975695)) and at one point the book covered some basic set theory (what union, intersection, etc. are along with simple Venn diagrams) in which things like "is $\{x\}$ an element of $\{x,\,\{\{x\}\},\,\{x,y\}\}$" were asked (actually, this is probably harder than any of the actual questions!) **(continued)**

Comment: and during the lecture I was trying to think of an analogy I could use, looked around the room, and I saw a trash can by the exit door (looked like [this](https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/b4eb87f8-999b-45e1-bc18-7b7bf7b751b4_1.363f2d6a224ecc1f1f15e43ad0b0b29f.jpeg), except with faded dark green paint, not shinny new like this one), which I realized would be perfect, so I picked it up and talked about things in trash cans, including one or more trash cans (each with various objects in them) in a trash can. Also the distinction between putting two erasers in the trash can and $\{x,x\} = \{x\}.$

Comment: *actually, this is probably harder than any of the actual questions!* --- In case anyone reading here missed the subtlety involved, note that if $x \neq y,$ then the answer is NO; and if $x=y,$ then the answer is YES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $x$ is an element (such as a real number $x\in \mathbb{R}$, or an integer, ...) while $\{x\}$ is a set where the only element is $x$ : it is called a singleton.

So $x\in \{x\}$ but these are not the same types of objects.

And if you take another element y, then $x\in \{x,y\}$ and $y\in \{x, y\}$.

I'm not sure the analogy will clarify it, but it's the same thing as a socket, and a socket in a drawer.
The socket is the only thing in the drawer now, but it's not the same as the drawer containing the socket. And you can add other sockets in your drawer...

**But be careful** : $x$ can also be a set itself, for instance $x=\{2, 3\}$, then $\{x\} = \{\{2, 3\}\}$ so $\{x\}$ is a set of set...

Comment: How do you know that $x$ is **not** a singleton?

Comment: Exact, but we then usually use another letter than $x$, but i'm going to edit to be clearer

Comment: What do you mean "not the same type of objects"? Do you know for a fact the OP is working in type theory? In ZFC the only type is "set".

Comment: Actually I'm not at ease with type theory. Maybe you can edit my answer with some comments on it and i'll approve. Or maybe you wan't to post another answer.